# Microservices, REST hateoas, and ressource owner

Tags: rest, hateoas, microservices

**Context**

I have to create a RESTFul API which deal with :

- Books
- Category of books

The application is splitted like this :

- Each client has an API key
- Each user of a client can manage (get/post/put/delete) multiple books / categories of books related to the client he is linked to.

Following the REST principle, only the person that creates the ressource, "the ressource owner" can manage this ressource.

**First problem**

However, in this context, it's possible for a user to share a book to another user related to his ecosystem, meaning that he cans share informations only with the users that share the same API key (the same client).

Does it mean that I have to manage an owner_list in my book object ?

**Second problem**

I told in the before explanations that I have API keys corresponding to a certain client. Should I have a client_id stored in my user object ? Permitting me to quickly know and share informations between users corresponding to this client_id ?

**Third problem**

Admitting that I want to work with REST Hateoas, in a Java context. Looking at how hateoas work, it seems that I have to create a specific object that permit me to hyperlink my ressources, like (in JSON) : {hateoas:{key:"user", link:"/users/1234"}} ? Or does it exist something better ?

**Last problem**

Admitting that I want to work with microservices architecture, and that I have :

- A user microservice (for authentication)
- A book microservice

I know that I should send informations through AMQP protocol when I need an information from a different microservice.

So :

- What kind of exchange / queue (topic, fanout etc...) should I use ?
- What kind of information should I send over the network ? Because, okay, I know where the ressource is, with hateoas, but what should I put inside the "tunnel" to have a response ?

Comment: `Following the REST principle, only the person that creates the ressource, "the ressource owner" can manage this ressource.` - This is not a REST principle.

Comment: Your first and second problem is about access control. I don't fully understand the second question. By the third, ofc. you can share links, but I am not sure it is okay to share the link of the REST service. I assume you will have multiple REST clients, which can appear in the browser. Probably you should share the links of them. I am not an expert of the message queue topic, I guess you can translate the HTTP request into an internal AMQP message. I assume there are tools, which can do this automatically.